# getting data from linkedin

Tags: appexchange

I have a requirement to get data from linked in and update it in salesforce.

For example : if a contact has designation : consultant in salesforce contact record. In linkedin if he has the designation as manager.

I want to update the designation in saleforce.I want to do this periodically for example every day.

Is there any app exchange app available or I want to do get the data using API?

Answer (score 0):

I built a tool specifically to do this - http://www.sifdata.com/services/

Basically, on a cadence(daily, weekly, month, etc.) I'll update your leads/contacts with the correct company/title. If there's been a significant change then I flag those up with a custom object called SifData Alerts